# Why Does Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu appear to have such a toxic culture?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, grappling, culture

I have noticed a lot of essentially toxic content relating to BJJ online.  It ranges from questionable to down right rude to (occasionally) completely unacceptable.

Here are a few examples.

Meme 1 Attacking higher grade members

[image: Meme 1 Attacking higher grade members]

Meme 2 Attacking other martial arts styles.

[image: Meme 2 Attacking other martial arts styles.]

Meme 3 Attacking lower grade club members.

[image: Meme 3 Attacking lower grade club members.]

It basically gives the impression of BJJ student's as bullies with a chip on each shoulder.

Is this really typical of their attitude?  Is this encouraged as part of a culture within the style?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether similar material exists in relation to other MAs? I would be very surprised if it didn't. No domain, in MAs or otherwise, has a monopoly on trolling. It's everywhere, a part of online culture, and whilst the memes you provide might not rise to the level of comedy genius, they're far from offensive or obscene. It would be a mistake to assume some undesirable homogenous BJJ culture exists at all, let alone on the basis of a few silly jokes. Significant diversity exists within and across most schools. There are bound to be poor ambassadors here and there.

Comment: @Futilitarian I also follow Karate, judo and some kungfu hashtags.  This seems to be something that is unique to BJJ clubs and MMA gyms.

Comment: @Futilitarian I would add that many martial artists I know also complain about the conduct of BJJ students due to things like leaving the changing room untidy etc.

Comment: Serious question: do you understand the concept of jokes?

Comment: And how is a joke about purple belts not doing warm-ups an "attack" on lower grade students? I feel like this is more that as an outsider you don't have the context to understand a casual culture.

Comment: (I don't fully understand the "flytrapper" reference but I suspect the 2nd meme could be less an "attack" on an outsider and more a brotherly acknowledgment of wrestlers (who also do jiujitsu) being immune to some attacks that work on BJJ players without a wrestling background.)

Answer (score 2):

I am not a BJJ student, but based on my experience in Capoeira, another martial art associated with Brazil, the machismo of the originating culture can't be discounted. Brazilian culture carries an emphasis on male virility which can translate out to an atmosphere which at least implies a "dog eat dog" setting where strength is rewarded and the kid gloves are off with an undertone that breaking the rules, or showing disrespect, will lead to you getting punished if only with something like a slap on the wrist. In practice, it's not usually that bad, with the strength being more show and implication than actual attacks, but I've seen enough people who made the mistake of making a *mestre*, particularly one from Brazil, look foolish by catching them with a sweep, and the *roda* becoming much more serious and you not being allowed to leave until you've been put in your place.

Not mentioned in the question, but I think germane to the question, is that this can also result in prejudice against women, non-binary folk, and non-heterosexuals (Capoeira is in a weird space in that we revere characters like [Madame Satã](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_Sat%C3%A3), but with an undertone that he was so manly in his crossdressing that it doesn't count), and when things get really bad, there is the issue of [sexual abuse](https://arodaunida.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/cmc_infographic_web.jpg), which the Capoeira world has been reeling from lately due to recent revelations about CDO leadership. Again, I'm not a BJJ person, so I don't know how prominent this is there, but for Capoeira, the machismo culture results in casual sexual aggression, especially from people of higher rank (and I'm pretty sure that Capoeira has some additional issues due to the "hidden/criminal" history of the style where no one wants to be a snitch, and politics can kill your progress dead if you cross the wrong people), and I've known a few women in BJJ who've commented on getting more than a few "friendly" squeezes during grapples and, again anecdotally, being openly gay can result in a surprisingly large number of heterosexual men engaging in groping as a show of dominance.

Answer (score 0):

In all martial arts there's a propensity for abusiveness to assimilate to the practice. Anyone who saw the Movie "Karate Kid" remembers the Cobra Kai. Martial arts that focus on brutal physical combat or lethal finishing moves will always tantalize the sociopathic. Martial arts for years have attracting kids with limited self confidence and low self esteem and any School environment, bullying by people who're far stronger or have hints of sadist tendencies. And the economic competitive nature of martial arts schools means many groups will accept anyone. Another thing is apathetic nature since schools don't punish offenders; once you're of age. By age 17-18 you're "Adult" I’m a grown person. Who has the right to punish me? Who has the right to tell me what to do? Hint: no one. If you're an A**hole outside the dojo you're gonna be one inside too. Martial arts, like military service or police work doesn't create sociopaths or bullies, but it does attract them.